# Web app 302 redirecting HTTP requests in Chrome 90 from embedded iframe

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers, session-cookies, samesite

We recently started having issues with a web app used internally at our organization. Most users have been using Chrome to access the web app. The issue seems to correspond with the release of Chrome 90. The web app has been in place for a couple of years working with previous versions of Chrome without issue in this regard.

The web app uses an embedded iframe from a 3rd-party vendor. The vendor app does an HTTP GET to a URL within our web app to indicate success or failure. We then close the iframe and update our app accordingly. This has worked fine until recently. Now it seems that the HTTP GET from the vendor iframe is being 302 redirected to our login.

[Example of 302 redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBlC0.png)

Prior to this and using MS Edge as the browser, the same HTTP GET gets a 200 response and our web app works as expected.

[Example of HTTP 200 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbXJR.png)

Since other browsers are continuing to work and there have been no significant changes to the web server, web app, or network access, we suspect something has changed with the latest version of Chrome and perhaps stricter security requirements. Why the 302 redirect? Does this have something with our SameSite cookie config? (Up to this point, we have done nothing specific with regards to SameSite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that with the latest updates to Chrome, we had to set the ASP.Net Session cookie headers to include "SameSite=None; Secure".

This article provided the answer: https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/

Comment: Thank you @fgantt  ... Much Appreciated!